# Bootstrap 5 dynamic height sticky sidebar with sticky footer CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm looking to create a position:sticky sidebar that has a header and footer, always visible and the middle content of the sidebar is scrolled. The page will have a variable height overall header.

I plan on using the Bootstrap 5 grid to setup the structure of the page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
  body {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    margin: 15px 0;
  }
  header {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .block {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .sidebar .block {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    height: calc(100vh - 295px);
    min-height: calc(100vh - 295px);
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 15px;
  }
  .header,
  .footer {
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<header>
  <div class="block">
    hi, my height can change.
  </div><!--/.block -->
</header>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="block">
      dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />
    </div><!--/.block -->
  </div><!--/.col -->
  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <div class="sticky sidebar">
      <div class="header">HEADER</div>
      <div class="block">
        1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>11<br>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br>20<br>21<br>22<br>23<br>24<br>25<br>26<br>27<br>28<br>29<br>30<br>31<br>32<br>33<br>34<br>35<br>36<br>37<br>38<br>39<br>40
      </div><!--/.block -->
      <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
    </div><!--/.wrapper -->
  </div><!--/.col -->
</div><!--/.row -->
</div><!--/.container-fluid -->
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y9ufqmjw/

See screenshot below at my first stab at it. When you are at the top I want the sidebar to fill the entire content area, regardless the size of the sidebar and the content area in the middle to scroll:
[Preview of sidebar top of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I58Yy.png)

When you scroll on the page I want the sidebar to fill in entire column height (as the header scrolls off, the sidebar should fill the entire column.
[Preview of sidebar bottom of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqQct.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with jQuery.

See the snippet below.

```js
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
    if ($('header').isInViewport()) {
      $('.sidebar .block').css('height', 'calc(100vh - 180px)');
    } else {
      $('.sidebar .block').css('height', 'calc(100vh - 130px)');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

header {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.block {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
}

.sidebar .block {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: calc(100vh - 180px);
  min-height: calc(100vh - 195px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 15px;
}

.header,
.footer {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <header>
      <div class="block">
        hi, my height can change.
      </div>
      <!--/.block -->
    </header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="block">
          dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br
          />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br
          />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br
          />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br
          />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br
          />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />dd<br />
        </div>
        <!--/.block -->
      </div>
      <!--/.col -->
      <div class="col-sm-3">

        <div class="sticky sidebar">
          <div class="header">HEADER</div>
          <div class="block">
            1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>11<br>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br>20<br>21<br>22<br>23<br>24<br>25<br>26<br>27<br>28<br>29<br>30<br>31<br>32<br>33<br>34<br>35<br>36<br>37<br>38<br>39<br>40
          </div>
          <!--/.block -->
          <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
        </div>
        <!--/.wrapper -->
      </div>
      <!--/.col -->
    </div>
    <!--/.row -->
  </div>
  <!--/.container-fluid -->
</body>

</html>
```